# Writing column remarks in an accdb file using pyodbc

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm trying to write/change column remarks (ie comment, descriptor) to existing columns in an access database file (accdb).

After connecting to the database I can see the remarks with this (if it exists):

```
cur = connection.cursor()
columnInfo = cur.columns( table='tableName' ).fetchall()

# to see the remark for the first column, for example:
print( columnInfo[0].remarks )
```

I'm at a loss, however, on how to write my own remarks to a column through pyodbc (or through anything else, for that matter). I'm also curious to know where this metadata resides. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well one option is to execute queries directly to manipulate the database. There are [examples of that approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060035/using-pyodbc-on-ubuntu-to-insert-a-image-field-on-sql-server) here on StackOverflow.

Google Code has [some good examples](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted) as well.

Comment: I would be ok with executing queries directly, though I'm still not sure what query statement I'd need to execute to change a column's remark. My google-fu is failing me here, I've tried variations with the words 'access', 'accdb', 'column', 'remark', 'change'. Nothing seems to be relevant - perhaps remarks just aren't used very much.