# How to save image to Postrgresql database via ODBC

Tags: image, postgresql, save, odbc, blob

I have table "images", column "image" type bytea

```
image = Новый COMОбъект("ADODB.Stream");
image.type = 1;
RecordSet   =   Новый COMОбъект("ADODB.Recordset"); 
RecordSet.CursorLocation    =   3;
RecordSet.ActiveConnection = Connection;
RecordSet.Open("Select * FROM images",Connection,3,2);
RecordSet.AddNew();
image.Open();
image.LoadFromFile("C:\database\1.jpg");
RecordSet.Fields("image").Value = image.Read(); 
RecordSet.Update();
RecordSet.Close();
```

This is one of my attempts.
 
    RecordSet.Fields("image").Value = image.Read(); - this code dont work. I got exception here.
Somebody knows working method?

Comment: What is the exception string?

Comment: Errors occurred during the execution of a multi-step operation. Check the value of all the states (it is translation).<br>   Text or number save without problem.

Comment: Show the error string. what is failing image.Read() or the assignment (=)?

Comment: Exception string or what? I need working method. This is just example that i     found but it don't works whith postgresql. May be  it works with another dbms, but i need postgre

Comment: example in which language? what libraries are you trying to use? where did you find the example, can you give a link?

Comment: this is 1C russian programm, but in other languages code will be almost the same. Only 1st and 3rd string will be different. I have problem only with images. Text or number i write without problem.

Comment: I meant c++, c# or python or any other lang?  Just give me the link where you found the example?

Comment: i cant find link but code are the same. Language is "1C", but syntax for odbc is same on c++ or another languages.

Comment: If you can give me code on c++

Comment: Simple python example using pyodbc, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060035/using-pyodbc-on-ubuntu-to-insert-a-image-field-on-sql-server. c++ example may take some time